# Ruby-Sketchup change color of faces

Tags: ruby, sketchup

I would like to color the top of this shape to rfClr, any ideas? I can change the whole thing Grey, but how to change the top to blue?

```
l=100
w=60
h=20
hl=8
slope=4
clr='Gray'
rfClr='blue'
ent = Sketchup.active_model.entities

        #---------Clear All
Sketchup.active_model.entities.clear!       
        #----------------
   model = Sketchup.active_model

    model.start_operation "Create Box"
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------      

    entities = model.active_entities
    group = entities.add_group
    entities = group.entities
       group.name="Box"
    @pt0 = [0, 0, 0]
    @pt1 = [0, 0, h*12+hl]
    @pt2 = [w*12/2, 0, 12*h+hl+(w/2)*slope]
    @pt3 = [w*12, 0, 12*h+hl]
    @pt4 = [w*12, 0, 0]

newface = entities.add_face(@pt0, @pt1, @pt2, @pt3 , @pt4)
    newface.material=Sketchup::Color.new clr
#newface.reverse!
    newface.pushpull l*12
```

[image]

Comment: Are you creating the mesh yourself? If so, then you should be able to set the material as you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this answer.
I guess it finds the faces that have a z value

```
vfaces = entities.grep(Sketchup::Face).find_all{|f| f.normal.z.abs != 0 }
vfaces.each{|f| f.material = rfClr }
```

Comment: I wouldn't think `abs` is necessary. I was surprised to see your question had an answer. Most Sketchup/Ruby questions see to go unanswered. (I know nothing of the API.)